# Having count returning zero rows when it should return something

Tags: sql, database, teradata, data-warehouse

```
SELECT             
        P.P_DESC AS P,     
        D.PD_NAME AS D,     
        D.GPE_NBR AS GPE,     
        D.GPE_GEN_NM,
        D.GPE_2_ ,        
        D.GPE_4c , 
        SUBSTR (TRIM(C.FILL_DATE__ID),1,6),      
        C.fill_Date__ID,   
        Prod.PD_DESC ,
        DMC.M_A_NBR,
        DMC.MAD_NBR ,
        DMC.FT_NAME,
        DMC.LA_NAME,
        DDB.DATE_DATE, 
        CAST((CURRENT_DATE - DDB.DATE_DATE)/365.25  as Int) M_AGE_TODAY,
        RXDOC.PB_FT_NAME || ' ' || RXDOC.PB_LA_NAME ,
        RXDOC.PB_ID,
        DT.D_TYPE_DESC ,
        CASE WHEN SDL.GEPE IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS FLAG,
        COUNT (C.PHR_C_ID) AS CCount, 
        SUM (C.AMT_PAID) AS Spend
    FROM   O_PHAR_C C           
    INNER JOIN _D D ON C.D__ID=D.D__ID   
    INNER JOIN _P P               
        ON  C.P__ID = P.P__ID 
        AND C.P__ID = 00001
    INNER JOIN _M_CURR DMC ON C.PB_M_CURR_ID = DMC.M_CURR_ID
    INNER JOIN _M DM ON DM.M__ID  = DMC.M__ID 
    INNER JOIN _DATE  DDB ON DDB.DATE__ID = DM.BIRTH_DATE__ID 
    INNER JOIN _M_ELIG_CURR DMEC ON C.PB_M_ELIG_CURR_ID = DMEC.M_ELIG_CURR_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BA_PROD_LAB_OWN.specialtyDList SDL
        ON D.GPE_NBR = SDL.GPE
        AND SDL.EFF_END_DATE >= CURRENT_DATE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _PD Prod ON DMEC.PD__ID = Prod.PD__ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _RX_PB RXDOC ON  C.PB__ID=RXDOC.PB__ID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _PHAR_D_TYPE DT ON C.PHAR_D_TYPE__ID = DT.PHAR_D_TYPE__ID      
    WHERE C.fill_date__ID BETWEEN 20170201 AND 20170228
        AND C.RE_I = 'N'   
        AND C.sR__ID IN (96,13,203)   
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10;
```

I want to use this query to return instances of the C.PHR_C_ID that are more than or equal to 10. However, when I limit my select statement to that column I get the desired result but when I add all these columns to it 'having count' returns 0. There are more than zero records; I think there is something wrong with the query.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you add in your fields and GROUP BY them, you get a count of records for that distinct list of fields. You can probably switch to a QUALIFY statement instead. This will sum up the results by distinct C.PHR_C_ID ignoring the other fields, and then return any fields for that distinct C.PHR_C_ID which has a count(*) >= 10.

```
SELECT             
                            P.P_DESC AS P,     
                            D.PD_NAME AS D,     
                            D.GPE_NBR AS GPE,     
                            D.GPE_GEN_NM,
                            D.GPE_2_ ,        
                            D.GPE_4c , 
                            SUBSTR (TRIM(C.FILL_DATE__ID),1,6),      
                            C.fill_Date__ID,   
                            Prod.PD_DESC ,
                            DMC.M_A_NBR,
                            DMC.MAD_NBR ,
                            DMC.FT_NAME,
                            DMC.LA_NAME,
                            DDB.DATE_DATE, 
                            CAST((CURRENT_DATE - DDB.DATE_DATE)/365.25  as Int) M_AGE_TODAY,

                            RXDOC.PB_FT_NAME || ' ' || RXDOC.PB_LA_NAME ,
                            RXDOC.PB_ID,
                            DT.D_TYPE_DESC ,
                            CASE
                                            WHEN SDL.GEPE IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'
                                            ELSE 'N'
                            END AS FLAG,

                          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.PHR_C_ID) AS CCount, 

                          C.AMT_PAID AS Spend

            FROM   O_PHAR_C C           


        INNER JOIN _D D 
                            ON  C.D__ID=D.D__ID   


        INNER JOIN _P P               
            ON  C.P__ID = P.P__ID 
            AND C.P__ID = 00001





        INNER JOIN _M_CURR DMC
            ON C.PB_M_CURR_ID = DMC.M_CURR_ID

            INNER JOIN _M DM 
            ON DM.M__ID  = DMC.M__ID 

            INNER JOIN _DATE  DDB
            ON DDB.DATE__ID = DM.BIRTH_DATE__ID 

            INNER JOIN _M_ELIG_CURR DMEC
                            ON C.PB_M_ELIG_CURR_ID = DMEC.M_ELIG_CURR_ID

            LEFT OUTER JOIN BA_PROD_LAB_OWN.specialtyDList SDL
                            ON D.GPE_NBR = SDL.GPE
                            AND SDL.EFF_END_DATE >= CURRENT_DATE

            LEFT OUTER JOIN _PD Prod
                            ON DMEC.PD__ID = Prod.PD__ID

      LEFT OUTER JOIN _RX_PB RXDOC 
                            ON  C.PB__ID=RXDOC.PB__ID 

      LEFT OUTER JOIN _PHAR_D_TYPE DT
                            ON C.PHAR_D_TYPE__ID = DT.PHAR_D_TYPE__ID


                 WHERE 
                C.fill_date__ID BETWEEN 20170201 AND 20170228
                AND C.RE_I = 'N'   
                AND C.sR__ID IN (96,13,203)   
               QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.PHR_C_ID) >= 10;
```

Comment: You must probably remove the GROUP BY and switch to COUNT/SUM OVER in the Select list, too

Comment: That double aggregation with GROUP BY and Qualify always gets me.

Comment: Thanks could you please provide examples as to how I can achieve that? Thanks

Comment: If I run the code like that, it will not return any result. However, when I modify it and remove some columns I will get the results that I am looking for.

Comment: @JNevill                SELECT             
                            P.P_DESC AS P,     
                              DMC.MAD_NBR ,
                            DMC.FT_NAME,
                            DMC.LA_NAME,
                            DDB.DATE_DATE, 
                            CAST((CURRENT_DATE - DDB.DATE_DATE)/365.25  as Int) M_AGE_TODAY,
 COUNT(*)  AS CCount,SUM(C.AMT_PAID) AS Spend  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8, 9
 HAVING COUNT(*) >=10

Comment: Limiting the select to those columns, and leaving the having count, returns the rows that I want to see. However, when I add more columns to get the full picture, by using your modified version of the query, I don't get any result.